# Bypass certificate validation with SSLSocketFactory

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, jax-ws

I am building a client side application which will connect to a third party server through a soap message. I am using jax-ws 2.1.9 and jdk 1.6_18 running on JBoss 4.2.3.

The problem itself is that the server, which is configured for testing purposes only, is returning an expired certificate, and, therefore, my application is throwing the exception below.

```
13:43:26,738 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: Could not transmit message
13:43:26,739 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.handleRemoteException(ClientImpl.java:404)
13:43:26,739 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)
13:43:26,739 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:172)
13:43:26,739 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:152)
13:43:26,739 ERROR [STDERR]     at $Proxy724.solicitarBaixaOperation(Unknown Source)
13:43:26,740 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.totvs.foundation.exchange.connector.ptu.implementation.v70_batch.InvoiceWriteOffConnector.process(InvoiceWriteOffConnector.java:91)
13:43:26,740 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 98 more
13:43:26,740 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not transmit message
13:43:26,740 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.client.HTTPRemotingConnection.invoke(HTTPRemotingConnection.java:255)
13:43:26,740 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.client.SOAPProtocolConnectionHTTP.invoke(SOAPProtocolConnectionHTTP.java:73)
13:43:26,741 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.invoke(CommonClient.java:339)
13:43:26,741 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:302)
13:43:26,741 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 102 more
13:43:26,741 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: org.jboss.remoting.CannotConnectException: Can not connect http client invoker. java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Thu Sep 11 09:35:00 GMT-03:00 2014.
13:43:26,741 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.useHttpURLConnection(HTTPClientInvoker.java:348)
13:43:26,742 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.transport(HTTPClientInvoker.java:137)
13:43:26,742 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:122)
13:43:26,742 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1634)
13:43:26,742 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:548)
13:43:26,742 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.client.HTTPRemotingConnection.invoke(HTTPRemotingConnection.java:233)
13:43:26,743 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 105 more
13:43:26,743 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Thu Sep 11 09:35:00 GMT-03:00 2014
13:43:26,743 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
13:43:26,743 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1611)
13:43:26,744 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:187)
13:43:26,744 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:181)
13:43:26,744 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1035)
13:43:26,744 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:124)
13:43:26,744 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:516)
13:43:26,745 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:454)
13:43:26,745 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
13:43:26,745 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1112)
13:43:26,745 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1139)
13:43:26,745 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1123)
13:43:26,746 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
13:43:26,746 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
13:43:26,746 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:904)
13:43:26,746 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
13:43:26,746 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.useHttpURLConnection(HTTPClientInvoker.java:277)
13:43:26,747 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 110 more
13:43:26,747 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Thu Sep 11 09:35:00 GMT-03:00 2014
13:43:26,747 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(CertificateValidity.java:256)
13:43:26,747 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:570)
13:43:26,747 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator.java:134)
13:43:26,748 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
13:43:26,748 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
13:43:26,748 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
13:43:26,748 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
13:43:26,748 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1014)
13:43:26,749 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 122 more
```

So, for testing purposes, I am trying to bypass those validations. I found some blogs and posts which all drove me to the code snippet below.

```
/**
Inner class for set a blind TrustManager
**/
public class BlindTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
    }
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
    }
}

/*Get the port instance of the web service interface created by JAX-WS*/
SolicitarBaixaPortType port = InvoiceWriteOffWebService.getInstance(serviceName, wsdlLocation);

/*set the socket factory*/
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
            ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new BlindTrustManager() }, null);
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
            ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProviderProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslSocketFactory);
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.BindingProviderProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslSocketFactory);

/*message is the Object Jax generated*/
response = port.solicitarBaixaOperation(message);
```

Although I had set the *SSLSocketFactory* the *CertificateExpiredException* is still be throwing. So it raises the following questions:

1. Am I doing it right?
2. How can I be sure that the connection sees my *BlindTrustManager* class? For I can't see any mention of it on the log.
3. How can I be sure of the right String that I need to pass to my *BindingProvider* request context for it can find my *SSLSocketFactory*?
4. Is there some other configuration that I must do in JBoss?

Thanks

Comment: 'For testing purposes' always strikes the fear of God into me. The real question is why has the certificate expired? Writing 'for testing purposes' code to circumvent that is only a way for leaking that 'for testing purposes' code into production, where it will remain, unexamined and insecure, for years. Solve the *problem*. Don't just treat the symptom.

Comment: I agree with you that this doesn't solve the problem, but the certificate is expired because the owner of the web service doesn't fix it on his testing environment. As I said before, it is a third party service which I do not have any ways to interfere. Is there a way to properly solve this issue whitout the owner's intervention?

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess as I'm not familiar with the framework, but if jboss is using url.openConnection() then I think you will need to set the JVM-wide default

```
javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
```

n.b. This may have wider implications, and maybe you could specifically whitelist this certificate if this works.